# Quartus II state machine, assign number to specific bits

Tags: verilog, state-machine, quartus

In Quartus II state machine I have a 8 bit input. In one of the state to state transitions I want to check that is lower 4 bits of input for example 7 or not

Code I added to the transition condition

```
input[3:0] == 7
```

but every time I want to make vhdl in gives me this error :

```
HDL file generation was NOT successful, Error (154013): Component 01 contains an illegal name character combination
```

I don't know whether I can do this checking this way or not
I don't know much about coding verilog and i'm using diagrams

Answer (score 1):

`input` is a reserved word - you can't have a signal named "input".

You probably want to use the name of your input signal instead (ie `input [7:0] foo;` ... `(foo [3:0] == 7)`)